# Loop to create cell array

Tags: matlab, cells

I have a structure named `data`. The structure has 250 elements and one field called `codes` (whose dimension varies).

As an example: `data(1).codes` is a `300 x 1` cell of strings and `data(2).codes` is a `100 x 1` cell of strings.

What I am trying to do is to create a big cell with three columns:  `id count codes` where `id` indexes the element number (1 to 250), `count` indexes the row of the string and `codes` are just the codes.

An example to make it clear:

```
for k = 1:size(data,2)
    id  = repmat(k,size(data(k).codes,1),1);
    count = linspace(1, size(data(k).codes,1), size(data(k).codes,1))';
    codes= data(k).codes;   
end
```

The loop above creates the columns I want. Now I just need to append them one below the other and then save to excel. If these where only numbers I knew how to concatenate/append matrices. But with cells I am unsure how to do it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
output = {};

for k = 1:size(data,2)
     id  = repmat(k,size(data(k).codes,1),1);
     count = linspace(1, size(data(k).codes,1), size(data(k).codes,1))';
     codes= data(k).codes;   

     output{1,1} = {output{1,1}; id};
     output{1,2} = {output{1,2}; count};
     output{1,3} = {output{1,3}; 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build up your output into a new cell array, allowing for pre-allocation, then concatenate all of your results.

```
% Initialise
output = cell(size(data,2), 1);
% Create output for each element of data
for k = 1:size(data,2)
    id  = repmat(k,size(data(k).codes,1),1);
    count = linspace(1, size(data(k).codes,1), size(data(k).codes,1))';
    codes = data(k).codes;   
    % add to output
    output{k} = [id, count, codes];     
end
% Vertically concatenate all cell elements
output = vertcat(output{:});
```

Note: this assumes `codes` is numerical, and the output will be a numerical matrix. If it isn't, you will need to do some cell conversions for your numerical data (`id` and `count`) like so:

```
id = repmat({k}, size(data(k).codes,1), 1);
count = num2cell(linspace( ... )');
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thank you (especially for including the extra step regarding non numerical fields)!